# How does one override the extend method in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In my backbone app, I want to have a list of all child classes of (the ones that extend from) a certain class `A`. To achieve this, I want to override the default `extend` method, however my (perhaps naive) approach doesn't work:

```
var A = Backbone.Model.extend({
  /* ... */
}, {
  __children: [],
  extend: function () {
    var Klass = this;
    result = Klass.__super__.extend.apply(Klass, arguments);
    Klass.__children.push(result);
    return result;
  }
});
B = A.extend({}, {className: "B"});
A.__children // === []
```

Why does this not work, is there some magic when overriding the extend method?

Comment: i am just wondering how did you manage to post a question and answer it  within a single second..

Comment: When posting a question, there is a small checkbox that says " Answer your own question". This practice is actually encouraged: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the extend method is special. As you can see from

```
> Backbone.Model.extend
function (protoProps, classProps) {
    var child = inherits(this, protoProps, classProps);
    child.extend = this.extend;
    return child;
  }
```

the `extend` method gets overwritten with the one of the parent class, whatever you try to make of it. So, the way to hack around this is to "fix" the extend method afterwards:

```
var enableChildTracking = function (Klass) {
    var old_extend = Klass.extend;
    Klass.__children = [];
    Klass.extend = function () {
        var That = this;
        var result = old_extend.apply(That, arguments);
        That.__children.push(result);
        result.__children = [];
        return result;
    };
};

var A = Backbone.Model.extend({});
enableChildTracking(A);

B = A.extend({}, {className: "B"});
C = A.extend({}, {className: "C"});
A.__children.map(function (child) {return child.className}); /* == ["B", "C"] */
```

Of course this way one could also override the extend in the Backbone.Model directly, or send an event or call a callback (a la ruby) in case of extension.